# Error "emails":"Please enter an array" when making a request to MailChimp API V2.0

Tags: python, mailchimp, mandrill

I have been trying to make a request to the V2 MailChimp API.

When I uses the following method :

```
    def get_subscriber_info(self, list_id, email):
        url = "https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/member-info.json"    
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
        payload = {"apikey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX9999XXX98X886544",
                   "id": "4hstitfbaa",
                   "emails":[{'email':"hi@byebye.com"}]
        }
        r = requests.get(url, params=payload,
            , headers=headers)
        return r.json()
```

I get this error: "emails":"Please enter an array"

However if I change the emails key to "emails[]" I get this error: "email" should be a struct.

I have read the documentation and am pretty sure I am formatting the params payload as it should be formatted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `emails = [{"email":...,"euid":...,"leid":...},...]` looks like what you need to send not just `{"email":}` ... at least according to https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php

Comment: @JoranBeasley `... each with with one of the following keys` I think one is enough.

Comment: ok you might be right ... the example they provide has all 3 ... but per the way the documentation is worded it seems like one should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `POST` request and send `payload` in JSON format:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: I tried sending as a POST request. If I send the payload raw I get the same errors as above. If I send as a json.dumps() I get the "You must specify a apikey value" error.

Comment: Mine said "Invalid MailChimp API Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXX9999XXX98X886544"

Comment: Yes you are right and I am wrong. I forgot to change params to data. Now request works.